# How to say “in English, X is called Y” in Japanese

Tags: grammar, translation

I’m in the midst of a conversation with some Japanese friends online, and I’ve run into a bit of a problem. I want to tell them the English names of certain characters, since the names are different in Japanese, but I’m not sure how to phrase it.

If I wanted to say “In English, A is called B”, would 「英語でAの名前はBです」 work? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is 「では」 that is more natural for Japanese-speakers than「で」.

You could say:

「Aの名前は、英語ではBです。」 or

「英語では、Aの名前はBです。」

Instead of 「です」, you could use 「になります」 or 「になっています」 as well.

Comment: Replacing です with 「になります」or「になっています」would make it more formal, right?

Comment: Not really.  It has little to do with formality.  It is just how native speakers speak.  You are trying to translate too directly from English.